# "ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _ssl" when launching from batch file

Tags: python, batch-file, ssl, anaconda, smtp

I want to send a mail via python script and launch the script with a batch file. I get the error "ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _ssl" when launching from the batch file, when running the python script directly from my spyder editor it works as intended.

I am using a Windows 10 and a freshly installed anaconda environment with python 3.8, which is installed into "C:\Users\Max".

My batch file looks like this:

```
"C:\Users\Max\anaconda3\python.exe" "C:\Users\Max\Documents\Python Scripts\script.py"
```

My Python Skript looks like this:

```
import smtplib, ssl
port = 465  
context = ssl.create_default_context()
with smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com", port) as server: 
   server.login("address1@gmail.com", "password")
   server.sendmail("address1@gmail.com", "address2@gmail.com", "message")
```

Why does the script behave differently when called from a batch file and how do I fix this?

Comment: The answer on your question is: The environment is different. That means the list of environment variables is different which is the reason why in one case `Python.exe` can find all the DLL files imported by your script while in other case the DLLs are not found because of different environment. Please read the Python documentation about [the import system](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html) and [sys.path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path) and [PYTHONPATH](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) referenced from this documentation page.

Comment: In all probability, the problem is the current directory is the difference between the two. Try `echo %cd%&pause` on a separate line before the one you've published. If the displayed directory is different, replace that `echo` line with `cd thedirectorythatworks` - and if the drivename differs, precede *that* with `X:` where `X` is the drivethatworks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I got it!

I first had to put "C:\Users\Max\anaconda3\condabin" in my PATH in order to use conda commands in my windows cmd, then modify my batch file to

```
call activate base
"C:\Users\Max\anaconda3\python.exe" "C:\Users\Max\Documents\Python Scripts\script.py" 
call conda deactivate
```

Comment: Problem solved, it seems - and clear solution published - excellent!